# How do I insert the missing column?

Tags: r, dataframe, sequence

My data frame looks like this:

```
df <- data.frame('2' = -.05, '3' = -.01, '5' = .2)
```

I would like to insert another column titled '4' which has the value 0, as well insert it into its correct position (the 3rd column). 
End result should look like:

```
df <- data.frame('2' = -.05, '3' = -.01, '4' = 0, '5' = .2)
```

I also need this to work given any data frame, the missing columns are filed in. For example:

```
df <- data.frame('2' = -.15, '6' = .11)
```

becomes

```
df <- data.frame('2' = -.05, '3' = 0, '4' = 0, '5' = 0, '6' = .11)
```

Thanks for any assistance or advice.

Comment: what you have tried so far ?

Comment: Try to print out your `df`. Your names in the example aren't even sticking (as they are numbers). Otherwise, you could use `df[,order(names(df))]`

Comment: So far my attempts have been to create a separate data frame of zeros with n rows and 1 column (n being the largest numeric column name (n = 5 in the first example)). Then i would transpose said matrix and fill in the available values. I guess what I am really asking is how you all attempt to do this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could do this in `base R`.  It is not recommended to have column names that start with numbers, so by default the `check.names = TRUE` in `data.frame`, so when we create the `data.frame`, it will have an 'X' appended as prefix.  To avoid that, use `check.names = FALSE`

Get the `names` of the 'data', convert it to `numeric`, get the `range` and find the sequenc

```
v1 <- Reduce(`:`, range(as.numeric(names(df))))
```

Then, we create a `data.frame` with 0 values with column names as 'v1'

```
df2 <- as.data.frame.list(setNames(numeric(length(v1)), v1), check.names = FALSE)
```

Assign the values in 'df2' based on the column names in 'df'

```
df2[names(df)] <- df
df2
#      2     3 4   5
#1 -0.05 -0.01 0 0.2
```

---

It can be converted to a function

```
f1 <- function(dat){
 v1 <- Reduce(`:`, range(as.numeric(names(dat))))
 df2 <- as.data.frame.list(setNames(numeric(length(v1)), v1), 
         check.names = FALSE)
df2[names(dat)] <- df
df2
```

}

```
df <- data.frame('2' = -.15, '6' = .11, check.names = FALSE)
f1(df)
#       2 3 4 5    6
# 1 -0.15 0 0 0 0.11
```

#### data

```
df <- data.frame('2' = -.05, '3' = -.01, '5' = .2, check.names = FALSE)
```

Comment: I really appreciate the help! May I ask what ':' does in the Reduce function?

Answer (score 0):

I've used tibbles instead of data.frames because they can use numbers as columns names (just have to escape them with backticks ```.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(`2` = -.15, `6` = .11)

fix_tibble <- function(x) {
form <- tibble( `2` = NA_real_,
                `3` = NA_real_,
                `4` = NA_real_,
                `5` = NA_real_,
                `6` = NA_real_)

bind_rows(form, x) %>%
  select(`2`,`3`,`4`,`5`,`6`) %>%
  .[-1,]}

fix_tibble(df)
```